# Windows 7 reboot makes my computer halt in a black screen before the loading bar screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, reboot

My laptop has been having this problem ever since I first tried Windows 7 since 2009. What happens is, sometimes, when I reboot it, it just hangs infinitely as described in my title. I can't ever really reboot it, so normally I just put it on standby and avoid installing critical stuff. When I do reboot it and get lucky that it doesn't hang forever, I have to make a full image using a backup utility so that I can restore it. I tried many fresh installs already but this always happens. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons for a black screen.

1. Anti Virus software (Symantec) can cause this, change brands
2. Video drivers can cause it, update the driver, or a bad video card/chip
3. File system corruption within the $Txf directory, see this link. Article was written for Vista but also applies to W7, although it was more common in Vista for some reason.
   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=946532
4. File corruption is the most common reason, it could be any critical file needed to load the OS, from the Master Boot Record to $Txf folder.

Comment: Yes, I think it is the 3rd or 4th reason. The thing is, how do I prevent file corruption of critical files needed to load the OS? Note that I even when I do nothing critical to the system, like install new drivers or update, it still happens at least 80% of the time.

Comment: It could be a bad memory module, bad hard drive, or motherboard. How old is this PC?

Comment: My laptop is pretty old actually, almost 4 years. I don't think it's a bad memory module since I recently changed it. It's hard to say it's the motherboard. I guess it's time to get a new laptop?